# Refreshing multiple things on site

Tags: javascript, ajax, vps

I'm running a coin flip minigame, where users can play against each other. It is using alot of ajax functions, saved into a js functions.
 It needs to be refreshed every few seconds, because there is a chat, game list and alert zone (different for each user and has to be dynamically displayed). 
It really slows my site (it is running on vps) and I'm looking for way to do fix it, because so far I can not handle more than 10 users active.
I thought about using sockets, or external servers for chat and rest, what would be the post option?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow - please read our [ask] page for hints on how to improve your question. Great question tend to provide quicker, better answers from the community

Comment: without knowing more about what you send or receive, I recommend minimizing a callback to only know if there is something that needs updating, as to minimize the footprint of the constant pings as much as possible. The result back could be as simple as 1 or 0 response, 011000, resulting in only having to fully refresh the data in the necessary sections...

Comment: web sockets would be a good choice especially for the chat since that's something that can result in many many requests, using websockets would decrease the http overhead. Here's an interesting read I found: http://www.peterbe.com/plog/are-websockets-faster-than-ajax

Answer (score 1):

you could do something like this:

setInterval(function(){ document.location.reload(true); }, 1000);

This would reload the page every second.

Comment: how would that help?